# Code resize dynamically in javascript not works fine

Tags: javascript, browser

I have this Modal code and I'm trying to calculate the width and the height dynamically and add this to a modal div , but when I put the trigger code inside a web site ( into a hosting online ) this resize code not works fine, not does the resize dynamically but when I test this code in a Xampp server ( in localhost ) it works fine.

I don`t want to use Jquery to avoid any conflict with the site.

In http://jesusbwebdesigner.com/staging_sdv/en below to slider there is a button call "open modal", that is the example

Any idea ?

```
<div id="myModalButton" class="modalBucket">
  <div class="modal-content-bucket">
   <span class="close-bucket">&times;</span>
  </div>
</div>

var modal = document.getElementById('myModalButton');
var modalContent = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-content-bucket');


modal.style.width = window.innerWidth;
modal.style.height = window.innerHeight;
modalContent[0].style.width = window.innerWidth - 40;
modalContent[0].style.height = window.innerHeight - 40;
```

Comment: can you provide your web address?

Comment: http://jesusbwebdesigner.com/staging_sdv/en/ below to slide there is a button call "open modal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add Width and Height in Pixel format. So update your method code in scriptBucket.js file with this one.

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.width = window.innerWidth+"px";
    modal.style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
    modalContent[0].style.width = (window.innerWidth - 40)+"px";
    modalContent[0].style.height = (window.innerHeight - 40)+"px";
    modal.style.display = "block";
    document.body.classList.add("open-modal-bucket");
}
```